# Chrome throwing mixed content error on website load

Tags: jquery

Recently added a SSL certificate to my new website and since then Chrome is throwing the following error message that I have not been able to resolve.

Anyone an idea how to fix this?

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.my-new-website.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. fadeslideshow.js:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at fadeslideshow.js:17
```

Comment: Add `s` to `http`  ex. `http` **s** `://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that since you're using page with ssl you cann not have content over unsecure service.

In practice it means that you can't use script which adress starts with `http`. It has to be `https`

Just change `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js` to `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js` in your HTML

As to error `fadeslideshow.js:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at fadeslideshow.js:17` it won't be a problem once you'll repair your jQuery.